# Поставить во всех записях MySQL одинаковое значение

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `bid_country`. Есть поле `date_create`. Оно пустое. Нужно обновить все записи, что бы значение этого поле было текущая дата. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
UPDATE
  bid_country
SET
  date_create = NOW()
```

Данный запрос поместит в поле `date_create` локальное время с учетом часового пояса. Если требуется время UTC лучше воспользоваться функцией `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`

```
UPDATE
  bid_country
SET
  date_create = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```